# Jquery Masonry only works in ajax loaded content on second click

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

I am loading content on my page using .load, and I have images being displayed using the Masonry plugin. The masonry is only kicking in on the second click to load the content however. the page in question is the photo page at http://ashevilleapothecary.info/
here is slightly stripped down code:

```
$(".navpage").click(function(){
    $("#floodcontent").load("photos.txt");
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('#photobox').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.photo'
    });
});
```

any help appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Masonry doesn't know about the change (new images loading) since there's no callback function to 'remind' masonry to organize the page again.

Use the imagesLoaded plugin option. This will fire a callback function once images are loaded and then the images will no longer overlap.

http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html#imagesloaded_plugin

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is definitely best practice, so thanks for that, but it hasn't fixed my problem unfortunately...

Comment: And to be more specific, it did actually fix part of the problem, that the images overlapped some of the time, but now, On the first click to load the page, the images are all just in a single column (with the proper spacing).